# how can I retried the grid based on different category wise display using foreach loop in MVC Cshtml Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my project I have Category.I want to display data like in View Below show It.

My category

- Cname  | Cvalue | CAllocation

My Category

- Cname  | Cvalue | CAllocation

My View page in i have using for Foreach functionality show my code of View in below:

```
@model IEnumerable<WealthApp.Model.Schema_Details>
<table>
@{ int i = 0;}
@foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.SType))
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">@Html.Encode(group.Key)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1"></td>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Schema Name</th>
                    <th>InvestmentType</th>
                    <th>Allocation</th>
                    <th>Lum_Sum_Amount</th>
                    <th>SIP</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var item in group)
                    {
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Encode(item.Schema_Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Encode(item.InvestmentType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Convert.ToString(Html.Encode(item.Allocation))%
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Encode(item.cal)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Encode(item.SIP)
                        </td>
                    }

                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
      i++;
    }
}
```

and in display after run this my application. I can Only One record. In grid In database 10  entries contain the table but it is retried the only one data. 
I can show you the View at below in Image:
[image]

My Sechema_details Model:

```
namespace WealthApp.Model
  {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using WealthApp.Model;
public partial class Schema_Details
{
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public int RID { get; set; }
    public string Schema_Name { get; set; }
    public string SType { get; set; }
    public string InvestmentType { get; set; }
    public int Allocation { get; set; }
    public int Lum_Sum_Amount { get; set; }
    public double cal { get; set; }
    public double SIP { get; set; }
    public int tr { get; set; }
    public virtual Risk_Tolerance_Type Risk_Tolerance_Type { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You have a `if (i == 0)` which means that you only ever display one row (at the end of the loop, you increment it, so its no longer `0` and in the subsequent iterations, `if (i == 0)` returns `false so none of the code is executed. (just remove it)

Comment: But the rest of the code wont work correctly anyway since you will be just generating more columns in the row for each 'group'. I assume you want to start a new row for each 'group'?

Comment: @StephenMuecke some times only one data available n som time 10 list of values comes.ya you understand perfectly ya i want too do that

Comment: What difference does the number of items in the collection make - your `foreach` loops will generate the one for each item in the collection.

Comment: in my database write now 2type one equity n 2 debt so i have to retried the 2 category n them of data.foreach loop in comes to category but in td its going first time only  @StephenMuecke

Comment: Sorry, but impossible to understand your comments.

Comment: i want display more row for each category data  now you understand@StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes, I know, so you need to create a new row for each group as per my previous comments - `@foreach (var item in group) { <tr> // add td elements </tr> }` - the `<tr>` need to be inside the loop, not before it

Comment: can explain in details how i can @StephenMuecke

Comment: You have a lot of bad practice in your code - using queries in views, nested tables etc. Edit the question to show your `Schema_Details` model and I'll add an answer later.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have done edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if (i == 0)` block means the you only ever generate that table for the first group (after the first iteration, `i == 1` and you never enter the `if` again. Removing that alone won't generate the html you want since you would also need to generate a new `<tr>` element inside the `@foreach (var item in group)` block (not before it).

However linq queries do not belong in a view (you making the code difficult to debug and near impossible to unit test) and the controller is responsible for generating the correct model to pass to the view. Start by creating view models to represent what you want to display

```
public class DetailVM
{
    public string Schema_Name { get; set; }
    public string InvestmentType { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P0}")]
    public double Allocation { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public double cal { get; set; }
    public double SIP { get; set; }
}
public class SchemaVM
{
    public string SType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DetailVM> Details { get; set; }
}
```

and in your GET method

```
IEnumerable<Schema_Details> query = .... // your query
IEnumerable<SchemaVM> model = query.GroupBy(x => x.SType).Select(x => new SchemaVM()
{
    SType = x.Key,
    Details = x.Select(y => new DetailVM()
    {
        Schema_Name = y.Schema_Name,
        InvestmentType = y.InvestmentType,
        Allocation = y.Allocation,
        cal = y.cal,
        SIP = y.SIP
    })
});
return View(model);
```

and the view becomes

```
@model IEnumerable<SchemaVM>
@foreach (var schema in Model)
{
    // don't use nested tables!
    <h3>Html.DisplayFor(m => schema.SType)</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>.....<thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach( var detail in schema.Details)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => detail.Schema_Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => detail.InvestmentType</td>
                    ....
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Side note: Property `Allocation` is a percentage so should be stored as a `float/double/decimal` with a value between 0 and 1. If you do not change it in the database, then use `Allocation = y.Allocation / 100D`